# Messed up System Files on PPC Mac

Tags: macos

My buddy deleted her `System` folder from her PPC Mac wanting to get that space for something else. She first copied it to another drive (she had a partitioned disk). She hasn't emptied the Trash Bin yet.

The screen just froze right after she moved the folder to Trash. We tried to use the install disk but even if we try Power-C on booting, it would try to continue, display the Apple logo page, then quickly follow it with black screen filled with dumps of hex codes and "We are hanging here..."

We have a Windows-based PC that we tried to connect using Ethernet cable but we can't find her computer from there. What should we do now?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the OS from the DVD included with the Mac. You will have the option to retain her personal data and programs.

---

If you have a different Mac and know how to connect the Mac's hard disk to it, you *could* try to find the System folder in the hidden `/.Trashes` directory and move it back. You should do this from the command line though, and there's no guarantee it'll work.